# Changing font awesome icon class at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control that has a text box and a button. I have repeated this user control n times using for loop in my main.aspx page

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            testcontrol newControl = (testcontrol)LoadControl("~/testcontrol.ascx");
            newControl.ID = "myControl-" + i.ToString();


            HtmlButton btnGenerateReport =newControl.FindControl("btnGenerateReport") as HtmlButton;
            btnGenerateReport.ID = "button_generate-" + i.ToString();
            btnGenerateReport.ServerClick += BtnGenerateReport_Click;


      }
```

my testcontrol.ascx looks like this

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 blockMe">
        <input runat="server" class="form-control" />
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <button type = "button" id="btnGenerateReport"  class="btn btn-default btnGenerateReport" aria-label="Left Align" runat="server">
           <span class="fa fa-cog" runat="server" id="gennerateReportSpan" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>

<br />
</div>
```

On ButtonClick I am trying to show spinning icon so that i can do some background process. I have subscribed to the HtmlButton OnServerClick method in mainpage.aspx

```
private async void BtnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl tt = ((System.Web.UI.Control)sender).Parent.FindControl("gennerateReportSpan") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl;
        tt.Attributes.Clear();
        tt.Attributes.Add("class", "fas fa-spinner fa-spin");
       
        Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

        }).ContinueWith((x) =>
        {

            tt = ((System.Web.UI.Control)sender).Parent.FindControl("gennerateReportSpan") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl;

            tt.Attributes.Add("class", "fa fa-cog");

        });
            

    }
```

I am trying to achieve the spinning effect by changing the attributes of the htmlelement. I am able to set new class i.e spinning but I am not able to reset it once the task is done. Is there any better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

This way you can never make it back to non-spinning because when your thread is finish you don't have no way to inform the client the way you make it.

I can think and suggest two ways

### first way - the ajax call

Ok, this is the most common way, to make an ajax call to a aspx file and wait for the return. You can find many example for this...

### second way - your way

You make your calculations call inside the page with a **flush just before the long running function** - when the calculations finish the page will continue to render the rest of it and change back the icon.

Here is a working example.

On aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1 id="changeme" style="color:blue">Header Test</h1>
    </div>
</form>

<%Response.Flush();%>
<%GenerateReport();%>            

<script>
    document.getElementById("changeme").style.color = "red";
</script>
```

on page behind

```
public void GenerateReport()
{
    // simulate the delay
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

### Last words

avoid the async on this web pages, is not desktop programming that you don't want to hold the render of the user interface. Here the user is on another computer and the call to you its a new thread by default, a thread to another computer. So all that is done with out any extra new thread creation.

Comment: you see my controls are dynamic . How do I accomodate that ? I am adding user-control using a for loop.

Comment: @Rohit I main see that call `BtnGenerateReport_Click` This is where you have add the delay... so the `JustMakeTheCalculations` is that function... now for the rest, I just give you the idea, think how to implemented on your  page - because you know it better than me